# Почему не работает exact? react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
  <BrowserRouter>
                    <Header />

                    <RandomPlanet />

                    <Route path="/"
                        render={() => {
                            return <h2>Welcome</h2>
                        }}
                        exact={true} />

                    <Route path="/people" component={PeoplePage} />
                    <Route path="/planets" component={PlanetPage} />
                    <Route path="/starships" component={StarShipPage} />

                </BrowserRouter>
```

Надпись welcome отражается во всех страницах. Что не так ?

Вот главный компонент

```
state = {
    hasError: false
}

swapiService = new SwapiService();

componentDidCatch() {
    this.setState({ hasError: true });
}

render() {

    if (this.state.hasError) return <ErrorMessage />;

    return (
        <div className="app">
            <SwapiServiceProvider value={this.swapiService}>
                <Router>
                    <Header />
                    <RandomPlanet />
                    {/* <Switch> */}
                    <Route path="/" exact>
                        {
                            () => {
                                return <h2 style={{ color: "red" }}>Welcome</h2>
                            }
                        }
                    </Route>

                    <Route path="/people" >
                        <PeoplePage />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/planets" >
                        <PlanetPage />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/starships">
                        <StarShipPage />
                    </Route>
                    {/* </Switch> */}
                </Router>
            </SwapiServiceProvider>

        </div>)
}
```

Comment: что такое `Router`? покажите его импорт

Comment: Вопрос решен с добавлением Switch и каждому роуту exact

Comment: import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря не нашел ответ на твой вопрос (если просто ставить return по отдает строку, и не переключает компонент ), но точно вижу что ты Switch забыл добавить. Главную страницу тоже стоит оборачивать в отдельный компонент, [тогда заработает](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-dew-9wmgh?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: создал новый проект и сделал 3 компонента. Работает как надо  с exact без Switch

Comment: `Switch` тут ни при чем.